# Get multiple select ID values

Tags: angular, angular-material, multi-select

I have a select loaded with records from the database and i need to obtain the ID values according to the options selected by the user. Some code:

HTML:

```
<label>PERSONAL</label>
<mat-select class="form-control" formControlName="personal" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of arrPer" [value]="item.per_IDPersonal">{{ item.per_nombreCompleto }}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

I need these values:

[image]

TS (try with for in)

```
for (const key in this.f.personal.value) {
    console.log(key);
  }
```

and I get

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Exactly what is it that you require? do you want `[1,3]` when 1st and 3rd options are selected or the whole object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) iterates over the properties of the object. In this case, they are the array indices.

[for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) can be used to iterate over the values of the object.

```
for (const value of this.f.personal.value) {
  console.log(value.per_IDPersonal);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nikhil ! I already tried with for of and it returns me 'undefined'

Comment: @AguFortini - What do you see in the console when you try  `console.log(this.f.personal.value);`?

Comment: I get the following: (2) [1, 3] if you select the first and third option. Now I would need to save these values in an array

Comment: @AguFortini - Then looks like your problem is solved right? You are getting the values you wanted to get in the question.